# Java/Apache Tika: How to get the last modified/created attribute of a file from URL

Tags: java, apache, http, metadata, apache-tika

I want to use Java to get the last modified time and the creation time of a file on an HTTP server. The file is located at a specific URL. The methods using `URLConnection` and `HttpURLConnection` yield the Last-Modified attribute from the HTTP header, but this is not the actual creation date of the file.

I have been reading that [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) is the library for the job. However, I have not been able to find a working example that does what I want. The closest example is perhaps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999258/get-the-last-modified-date-of-an-url). But when I run the code given in that post, it does not yield the last modified attribute.

I'm using partly an approach given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18100962/4736556) answer that I think might work, but currently does not print anything.

```
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();


URI u = new URI("https://sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2015/QTR4/master.idx");
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(u)));

parser.parse(is, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
System.out.println("Creation Date" + metadata.get(Metadata.CREATION_DATE));
System.out.println("Last Modified Date" + metadata.get(Metadata.LAST_MODIFIED));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are downloading the file using URLConnection, the HTTP headers are hidden from Tika.

All what Tika can read here is the same than if you had saved your file and opened a stream on it

It means that creation date and last modified will be the ones used when saving the file (the same that you can see using your OS browser [Windows explorer, nautilus...]).

If you need to read HTTP headers on that file and only that, do not use Tika but either directly the `HTTPUrlConnection` or any other HTTP client like (https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/) or the methods proposed in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999258/get-the-last-modified-date-of-an-url?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I had that last answer linked in my original post. I want to use the first example the author of that question gave, but his example did not give any Last Modified attribute when I ran it. The HTTP headers do not seem to be returning the correct information regarding the creation of the file, that's why I'm seeking to use Tika.

Comment: I want to retrieve the metadata of the file, like given in the answer's first example.

Comment: But as I said, Tika will not access the HTTP Header information that you want to read. It will extract metadata from the file itself. And since idx file are not handled by Tika it cannot read the information inside (and more its a simple txt file so it does not contain metadata like doc or pdf for instance).